# Render utf-8 as a tag in Django HTML

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

Question: Is is possible to decode a tag in Django HTML?

Context:

I'm having trouble rendering utf-8 with a Django tag and I am not sure what would be the best method of rendering it.

Here is my problem, I get the variable as follows: b'Line1\r\nLine2\r\nLine3'. Which is fine because once I get it and decode it, it displays properly in the command prompt. Now this is not the case when it renders it as a html page since it treats it as a string and it is all displayed in 1 line vice 3. Does anyone know what would be the best way of having handling this?

Comment: So there are a couple of things here. One, my experience has been that it's easiest to work with Unicode objects as instance fields, so unless something really compelling is forcing your hand I'd do that. Two, linefeeds won't actually render as new lines in HTML - they're treated as whitespace. There's a filter to add `<br />` tags in place, if that's appropriate to your situation - `linebreaks` or `linebreaksbr`.

Comment: Thanks, the 'linesbreaks' was the best solution for me.